How to get latitude, longitude and altitude frm jpg file using VBA in Microsoft Access
How to get latitude, longitude and altitude from JPG file using VBA in Microsoft Access ? I have found out in the internet, that Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) Library can be used:
img_file.Properties("GpsLongitude").Value(1).Value` (degrees), Value(2).Value (minutes), Value(3).Value (seconds),

It works, but this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wiaaut/-wiaaut-startpage
says:

We're no longer updating this content regularly. Check the Microsoft Product Lifecycle for information about how this product, service,
technology, or API is supported.

what is very disturbing.
And Shell Control and Automation object:
objFile.ExtendedProperty("Latitude"), ("GPSLatitude"), ("GPSLatitudeDecimal"), etc.

doesn't work.
Maybe File System Object. Is it going to be deprecated really ? And what about Shell Object ? (https://www.reddit.com/r/vba/comments/1cyptg5/microsoft_is_gonna_to_shut_down_vbscriptdll/?rdt=49733)
Thank you.
